# Use OR Clause in queryover in NHibernate

Tags: c#, sql, nhibernate, queryover

I am using Nhibernate. I am writing query through queryover method. I am able to write and clause as in code below. Its working fine.

```
db.QueryOver(Of Users)()
  .Where(Function(x) x.Role = "Guest")
  .And(Function(x) x.Block = 0)
  .And(Function(x) x.APPID = appId)
  .List();
```

But I want to use `Or` clause instead of `And`, or combination of both. How can I implement this. Thanks

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Here is description how we can build OR with NHiberante

- [NHibernate QueryOver with WhereRestriction as OR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24608118/)

The syntax *(in C# as the tag says)* is:

- `Restrictions.Or(restriction1, restriction1)`
- `Restrictions.Disjunction().Add(restriction1).Add(restriction2).Add(...`

In this case, it could be like this *(again in C#, while question seems to use VB)*:

```
db.QueryOver<Users>()()
  .Where((x) => x.Role == "Guest")
  .And(Restrictions.Or(
       Restrictions.Where<Users>((x) => x.Block == 0)
     , Restrictions.Where<Users>((x) => x.APPID == appId)
  ))
  .List<Users>();
```