# NHIbernate add OR Criteria Query to existing criterias

Tags: c#, sql, hibernate, nhibernate, queryover

I know how to add OR restriction using `Disjunction()` but i need add to this group of criterias, and i alwasy require at least 2 criterias. Im wondering how can I add single OR to existing criterias.

Semi code example.

`model.RootCriteria.Add(restriction)` <- restriction one (e.g. name like 'name')

Next after few lines i want to add AND or OR restriction to already existing depending on variable.

`if(AND)
    model.(Here add AND restriction)`<- add AND to existing what is only model.RootCriteria.Add(restriction) and it works

`else if(OR)
    model.(Here add OR restriction)` <- add OR to existing what **i dont know how** to do this

output i want to receive is:

`Where name like 'name ' (AND or OR) second restriction;`

Answer (score 0):

The way how we can work with criteria is always by `.Add()` opertion, which takes `ICriterion`

```
var criteria = session.CreateCriteria<Employee>();
    criteria.Add(
      Restrictions.On<Employee>((x) => x.LastName).IsLike("Xyz", MatchMode.Start)
    );
```

even in case we want to use OR, we have to add that via .Add(), like this:

```
    criteria.Add(Restrictions.Or(
        Restrictions.On<Employee>((x) => x.FirstName).IsLike("Abc", MatchMode.Start)
        , Restrictions.On<Employee>((x) => x.FirstName).IsLike("Def", MatchMode.Start)
    ));
```

The trick is that `Restrictions.Or` returns `ICriterion` as well...

Also check these:

- [Use OR Clause in queryover in NHibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24817319/)
- [NHibernate QueryOver with WhereRestriction as OR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24608118/)
- [15.2. Narrowing the result set](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#querycriteria-narrowing)

Comment: ur example will be `where lastName like 'Xyz' AND ( firstName like 'Abc' OR firstName like 'Def')`. I just want to add OR to current critarias in statement. why theres no simple .AddOR() ir .AddAnd() function?

Comment: That was an example. So, solution for you: Firstly check which two statements must be joined with OR. Then, place them in `Restrictions.Or` and the result `.Add()` to criteria. NO other way... But this is working for many of us ... long time ;) Also, check my links to `Disjunction` ... if you have more statements