# NHibernate - How to QueryOver in joined table with restrictions

Tags: c#, join, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, queryover

I am stuck with a SQL query (using NHibernate 4).

I have 2 tables (Client and Technology) with many-to-many relationship so I created a junction table called ClientTechnology.

I am trying to retrieve all the Technologies available (that are non-custom) PLUS all the Technologies available (that are custom) and belong to a given Client.

In SQL this is the statement:

```
declare @clientId int = 1

        select * from
        [dbo].[Technology] t
        where t.IsCustom = 0
        union
        select t.* from
        [dbo].[Technology] t
        join [dbo].[ClientTechnology] ct
        on ct.TechnologyId = t.Id
        where t.IsCustom = 1 and ct.ClientId = @clientId
```

My Fluent Mapping for Client table is:

```
public ClientMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id);
        Map(x => x.Name).Not.Nullable();
    }
```

For Technology table is:

```
public TechnologyMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id);
        Map(x => x.Name).Not.Nullable();
        Map(x => x.IsCustom).Not.Nullable();

        HasMany(x => x.ClientTechnologies)
            .Access.ReadOnlyPropertyThroughCamelCaseField(Prefix.Underscore)
            .Table("ClientTechnology")
            .KeyColumn("TechnologyId");
    }
```

and finally the junction table ClientTechnology:

```
public ClientTechnologyMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id);
        Map(x => x.Alias).Not.Nullable();
        Map(x => x.IsDeleted).Not.Nullable();

        References<Client>(x => x.Client, "ClientId");
        References<Technology>(x => x.Technology, "TechnologyId");
    }
```

I a open to different options to achieve this.
**Assuming I have available a Client object** (the ClientId)
I could retrieve first a list of Technologies that match the requirement IsCustom = false
and then retrieve a list of Technologies that match the requirement
IsCustom = true AND "the provided client is the owner of this custom technology"

Within a method `public IEnumerable<Technology> GetTechnologies(Client client)` that must return the enumerable of Technology (given a Client instance)

I have tried the following to retrieve globalTechnologies:

```
var globalTechnologies = _session.QueryOver<Technology>()
            .WhereNot(x => x.IsDeleted)
            .WhereNot(x => x.IsCustom)
            .List();
```

And the following for customTechnologies whose owner is the client:

```
Technology technology = null;
        ClientTechnology clientTechnology = null;
        var customTechnologies = _session.QueryOver<Technology>(() => technology)
            .JoinAlias(() => technology.ClientTechnologies, () => clientTechnology)
            .WhereNot(x => x.IsDeleted)
            .Where(x => x.IsCustom)
            .Where(clientTechnology.Client == client) //this doesn't compile
            .List();
```

but **I don't know how to access the junction table (joined) in order to apply the restriction**.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, the only problem is, that you do not provide Expression inside of the `.Where()`, so this should do the job:

```
// instead of this
// .Where(clientTechnology.Client == client) //this doesn't compile
// use this
.Where(() => clientTechnology.Client == client)
```

But I would go even farther. We should be able to creat subquery, which

1. will return only such **`Techonology.Id`** which are belonging to client.
2. we then can use also OR and have one query which would either select these who are:

   - NOT IsCustom or
   - Do belong to Client

How to create subquery you can see here:

- [How to do a QueryOver in Nhibernate on child collection](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27478172/1679310)

And example with OR

- [Use OR Clause in queryover in NHibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24817319/1679310)
- [NHibernate QueryOver with WhereRestriction as OR](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24608118/1679310)

Comment: Excellent! That was my missing piece. It worked great. Thank you.
Very complete answer. I will investigate your suggestion as it seems more efficient.